# how to create alert in prometheus if metric is exist

Tags: prometheus, alert, monitoring

I have this metric
`something_is_wrong{Cluster="test-db",} 1`
the metric only apper if there is a problem so how can I create alert that triggerd when the metric exist, (other than something_is_wrong ==1)

Answer (score 0):

Alert rule is triggered when there is result of the query. So you can simply specify `expr:` as `something_is_wrong{Cluster="test-db"}` for your situation. Your alert rule will look something like this:

```yaml
  - alert: Something_wrong
    expr: something_is_wrong{Cluster="test-db"}
    labels:
      severity: EXTREME
    annotations:
      summary: Something wrong happen
```

Expressions like  `> 0` or  `== 1` are just filtering metrics based on value. You can use them as part of usual query. And similarly you can use simple metric selector without any conditions in alert rule expressions.